# "dlopen failed: is 32-bit instead of 64-bit" in tests only

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, archlinux

I'm having a set or Gradle modules that uses the core module based on c++ code:

- Core (C++ with JNI glue, `aar` with `libxyz-jni.so`)
- Tests (Android instrumentation tests)
- App (regular Android app)

`Core` module includes native 32 bit `libxyz-jni.so` compiled for `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` and is compiled to `aar`. It does not have `arm64` libraries.

`App` module depends on `Core` and is working on `arm64` hardware device without any issues (is able to load `libxyz-jni.so`)

`Tests` depends on `Core` and fails to load `libxyz-jni.so` (with `System.loadLibrary(..)`) with following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/package.tests.test-2/lib/arm/libxyz-jni.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

I've checked tests apk not to contain any arch except `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`. The tests can run in android emulator but can't on 64 bit hardware device with Android Nougat. The App can run on arm64 device.

That's the difference between tests and app in terms of loading library?

Comment: x86 and armeabi are both 32-bit. You need one that is compiled for arm64 - how you achieve that, I'm not quite sure. You can't mix "bitness" between shared libraries and application using them (the only place where this works is when calling the OS from the application, and that is done via a special mode-switching interface, which is necessary even for "same bitness", because kernel-mode and user-mode behave differently)

Comment: i've just tried in Nougat arm64 emulator and i can run App but can't run Tests though native libs are absolutely the same for tests and app. How can you explain 32 bit 'libxyz-jni.so' can be loaded on `arm64` device/emulator in App but can't in tests? An how to make it working in tests too?

Comment: It can't, you are loading the x86 version of the app and it's library (or something like that). You need matching pairs of executable and libraries. I can't tell you exactly what steps you have to go through to achieve that, but I'm developing code for both x86 and ARM, and every now and again, I run into the problem that I've got mixed up libraries - it gives this problem, and you have to solve it by getting the correct bitness and processor architecture in place.

Comment: both `tests` and `app` use the same `core` with `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` 32 bit `libxyz-jni.so`. I can confirm app can run on both `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64` (both hardware device and emulator) and x86 (emulator). the tests can't run on `arm64` and i can't figure out why

Comment: Maybe [this](https://source.android.com/source/64-bit-builds) or [this](https://corbt.com/posts/2015/09/18/mixing-32-and-64bit-dependencies-in-android.html) can help you.

Comment: thanks for the links - i've found them before i asked the question. the second link  will not help for sure as there is no lib archs mixing here. probably i should read the first one again

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see what libraries your app is using at runtime. You can do this with these commands:

```
# get your running pid
adb shell ps | grep <your package name> | tr -s ' ' |  cut -d ' ' -f 2 
32333
adb shell lsof | grep 32333 | grep so
.xxx 32333    u0_a222  mem       REG             259,30    133152       2629 /system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so
.xxx 32333    u0_a222  mem       REG             259,30     30824       2759 /system/lib64/libmemalloc.so
```

As you can see in this case Android has loaded lib64 libraries. If you want it to default to loading 32-bit libraries, you need to have lib/armeabi-v7a/lib.so in your **APK**.

If you have your libraries somewhere else in the APK, and you extract, and load dynamically, Android won't know they are 32bit.